# Windows Scheduled Task HostName Placeholder

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, hostname

Hi I need to run a service on start up that cannot be run using the system user. (I am using Windows Scheduled Task Manager for this)
Under user is there a way to have a placeholder for the hostname vs a hard written hostname because when autoscaling the hostname changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear enough to fully understand the situation.

But perhaps you can make use of:
Localhost

Or the environment variables:
%Username%
%Userdomain%